# Can I use only 1 call intent (onclick) for all the buttons in xml - Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, call

Can I use only 1 call intent (onclick) for all the buttons in xml, then the value (phone number) that will be passed to the intent, is based on what button was clicked?

Instead of this Java Sample:

```
 public void CallRedCross(View call) {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:09079338303"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
}

public void CallViracMPS(View call) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:09183242541"));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
```

I should only have 1 Call Intent for all the buttons.

```
public void CallPhone(View call) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: **BUTTON VALUE** "));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
```

[image: Please Check Sample Image here...]

Comment: pass your json value in it .......

Comment: try to go for recyclerView : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you could easily make your Intent a class level variable if that makes you feel better, but why do you want to use one intent for all of them. An intent is nothing more then an "intention" or an action that will be taken. I prefer to make an IntentFactory that passes the required parameters and returns the intent for the caller to use. This allows all intent management and changing of activities to live in one central location. Here is an example.

```
 /**
 *
 * Created by App Studio 35 on 6/27/17.
 */
public class IntentFactory {

    /**
     *
     * @param context
     * @return intent
     */
    public static Intent getLoginIntent(Context context, boolean launchedFromNotification, String idOfDetailToOpen){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Globals.INTENT_KEYS.KEY_FROM_BADGE_ACCESS, launchedFromNotification);
        intent.putExtra(Globals.INTENT_KEYS.KEY_ID_OF_DETAIL_TO_OPEN, idOfDetailToOpen); 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        return intent;

    }
    /**
     *
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static Intent getSettingsIntent(Context context){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SettingsActivity.class);
        return intent;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param filePath
     * @param subject
     * @param body
     * @return
     */
    public static Intent getSendImageIntent(String filePath, String subject, String body){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/jpg");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + filePath));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        return Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share File");

    }
    /**
     *
     * @param toEmailAddresses
     * @param subject
     * @param body
     * @param uris
     * @return
     */
    public static Intent getEmailIntent(String[] toEmailAddresses, String subject, String body, ArrayList<Uri> uris) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, toEmailAddresses);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        if(uris != null) {
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

        }

        return Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail...");

    }
    /**
     * Used to launch to app details screen for toggling of permissions or other things
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static Intent getShowAppDetailSettingsIntent(Context context){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        return intent;

    }

}
```

and of course you would customize this for your own personal intents. But it is not a heavy object, so I would prefer legibility and clean maintainable code over finding a way to reuse the Intent. Although you could certainly just move it up to a class level if you would like that way you are just referencing the class level variable Intent if preferred.

Apologies, I just reread it, so you are trying to use the button pressed to represent which string to pass. You can do this with the android:tag element by simply putting the values inside the tag if your list is static.

However, if your list is dynamic then your bindView should contain a click. Your constructor of the Adapter should take an interface for callback of click and you can pass out clicked model associated with the index and of course at that time use the model.getTelephoneNumber to pass to your method. Does that make sense?

As requested to use the TAG method for your static list you could do:

```
public void CallRedCross(View call) { 
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); 
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+call.getTag())); 
    startActivity(callIntent); 
}
```

Of course I merely pointed you to using the tag, the above code is your code.

Comment: Hi Sam! Yes. my content of my list are all static, they just looked like a listview. I am interested on the android:tag element you introduced since I am not yet familiar with JSON and still newbie on android/java. I want to know the fastest/easiest approach to be used as possible.

So you mean, I can just add a number on android:tag in xml like this,
android:tag="09163167865"? 

then how can i call that in my existing call intent? Thanks!

Comment: Correct, you can just do your myView.getTag() in the setData and it will pull from the XML set tag

Comment: In fact if you really want to be lazy haha, you can put an onClick listener on all of them to the same method that accepts the public view and just get view.getTag from there

Comment: Hi Sam, :D
Yeah, this page is not the main focus on my app so I dont take too much attention on this. I just want to "somehow automate" it to avoid repeating codes. 

btw, it is not working.  
Or am I just wrong? :D
 
public void CallRedCross(View call) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse((String) call.getTag()));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }

Comment: OMG! It's working now @Sam.

It should be:

    public void CallRedCross(View call) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+call.getTag()));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }

Thank you so much!

Perhaps you can update your answer to like this so i can accept it?

Comment: Excellent, I'm happy to hear I set you on the right track. Great job getting it finalized :). I updated my answer. Thanks